# What does this error message mean in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, error-handling

I got the following error message when I want to count a pyspark dataframe with ~12 million rows.
Also I got a error messages when I want to convert the dataframe into a pandas. So every inspect function is a kind of this error like in the image. What can I do?
[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Spark, you have to types of functions :

- Transformations : They return usually a dataframe and are evaluated lazily. For exemple select, where, groupBy etc ... they are almost instant to execute and just validate that the structure of the dataframe fits the operation
- Action : They are the final step of the transformation chain. An action will trigger the execution of all the previous transformation. For exemple : show, count, collect, toPandas ...

Because of that system, if something is wrong during a transformation, the action cannot be resolved. That is the message you see. You do not know which transformation is failling, you just know that somewhere, in your cluster, the data and the transformation you want to apply creates an error.